# PHP multidimensional array combine

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am hoping to find help how to get to such structure:

```
[pad] => Array
    (
        [padi] => Array
            (
                [Date] => 2016-01-01
                [Val] => 1
                [Premium] => 100
            )
        [padi] => Array
            (
                [Date] => 2016-04-01
                [Val] => 1
                [Premium] => 200
            )
        [padi] => Array
            (
                [Date] => 2016-07-01
                [Val] => 1
                [Premium] => 300
            )
        [padi] => Array
            (
                [Date] => 2016-11-01
                [Val] => 1
                [Premium] => 400
            )

    )
```

I have 4 variables:

```
$p1 = array('padi' =>
                    array('Date' => $Date_0, 'Val' => $Val, 'padiPremium' => $padiPremium_0));
$p2 = array('padi' =>
                    array('Date' => $Date_1, 'Val' => $Val, 'padiPremium' => $padiPremium_1));
$p3 = array('padi' =>
                    array('Date' => $Date_1, 'Val' => $Val, 'padiPremium' => $padiPremium_1));
$p4 = array('padi' =>
                    array('Date' => $Date_1, 'Val' => $Val, 'padiPremium' => $padiPremium_1));
```

I have already tried with `array_push`, `array_merge` and `array_combine` and that didn't work for me at all or just my approach was wrong.
I would be gratefull to any suggestions !

Comment: you can't use the same key "padi" for all elements inside "pad" array

Comment: your desired structure is invalid, as the array keys have to be unique

Comment: why cant it be just `0, 1, 2, 3` numeric keys? why **padi**?

Comment: It's okay if they are all `0, 1, 2, 3` but all i managed to get is `padi, 0, 1, 2` ...

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood you, you are trying to merge 4 arrays:

```
$merged = array();
$merged[]=$p1;
$merged[]=$p2;
$merged[]=$p3;
$merged[]=$p4;

var_dump($merged);
```

You cannot have multiple of the same key in an associative array (in you case: `padi`).

Comment: perhaps simpler: `$merged=array($p1,$p2,$p3,$p4);`